# ImportError: cannot import name 'UnicodeWriter' from 'pandas.io.common'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am getting this error in this line:

```
sample_submission.to_csv('submissions/submission.csv', index=False, float_format='%.4f')
```

**Traceback:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-227-f01c3d31b8ad> in <module>
---> 33     sample_submission.to_csv('submissions/submission.csv', index=False, float_format='%.4f')


~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal)
   3178             when appropriate.
   3179         decimal : str, default '.'
-> 3180             Character recognized as decimal separator. E.g. use ',' for
   3181             European data.
   3182 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py in <module>
     21 from pandas.core.dtypes.missing import notna
     22 
---> 23 from pandas.io.common import (
     24     UnicodeWriter,
     25     _get_handle,

ImportError: cannot import name 'UnicodeWriter' from 'pandas.io.common' (/home/kriti/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py)
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: does your data contains unicode characters?? There seems to be problem with the init.py file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your pandas version? This does not happen in pandas 1.0.1. May be try upgrading your pandas to see if you still get the error.

Comment: downgrading to 0.23,0.24 helped me. This error only occured in 1.0 pandas version

Comment: @Pygirl I am glad it is resolved. Did it also work with version `1.0.1`? `0.24` is an old pandas version and you may be missing a lot of new functionality and improvements.